# Restoring git references to a folder through different branches

Tags: git

I have a question for git experts, as I believe achieving something like this is possible but after days scouring though documentation I still haven't found any clue about how to do it.

Basically, I have created a secondary branch from a git repository: this secondary branch is basically a "cleaned-up" version of the main one, so I erased many uninteresting folders inside it, and added a couple new ones. I've worked for quite some time with this configuration and it works pretty well: with a rebase I can get the latest updates from the folders I care about, while uninteresting ones remains unavailable. However, recently I got asked to include, in this "clean" branch, one of the folders I previously deleted. How can I do that so that a rebase will always bring updates from the master branch to my secondary one?

I could copy-paste the folder in the new branch, but I fear that by doing this way git wouldn't recognize the two folder versions as the same one. At the same time, the "cleanup" commit was huge, so I really wouldn't want to undo it with cherry-pick just to re-do it again for every folder but the one I want to restore.
Is there a faster way?

To summarize the issue "graphically", this is how branches look like:

**Master**

```
/
 > folderA
 > folderB
 ...
 > folderZ
```

**NewBranch**

```
/
 > folderA
 > newFolder
```

All I would like to do is to "bring" folderZ back to NewBranch, so that when I made modifications to it in Master branch, those modifications can also go to NewBranch through a rebase. Is it possible?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you remove folderZ in a standalone commit you can revert that commit, otherwise if you remove folderZ in a big commit with other folders a revert will restore all those folders, then you'll have to remove again the remaining folders.

Comment: sadly I already removed it along with lots of other folders. So you say there is no alternative to manually undo the whole commit and re-do it for everything but the folder I need to restore... thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing what you describe as doing—it seems like you're just making extra work for yourself—but if I understand the setup correctly, it's quite trivial to "bring back" the set of files you'd like.  I'll list the commands first here, and then describe what's going on, since you might want to change the commands a bit, depending on what you're really doing, and how you prefer to have things.

What you will need to do:

- check out your "cleaned up" branch
- use `git checkout` in its dangerous mode, or `git restore` if you have Git 2.23 or later, to extract the files you want included
- use `git commit` to make a new commit *on* your "cleaned up" brnach

and you're basically done.  That is, assuming modern (2.23 or later) Git:

```
git switch clean
git restore --source=dirty --staged --worktree -- path/to/folder
git commit
```

> I could copy-paste the folder in the new branch ...

That's what the above three commands do.

#### What's going on

Git is not about *folders* (not at all: commits do not, and cannot, *store* folders, for a rather silly technical reason).  Git isn't even about *files*, though commits do store files.  Git is really all about the *commits*.  So we need to know exactly what a commit is and does for us.

Each commit is *numbered*, with a random-looking but globally unique<sup>1</sup> number that is normally expressed in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) as a *hash ID*.  This raw hash ID is how Git *really* retrieves commits.

Each commit stores two things:

- It has a full snapshot of *every file*, in a compressed, de-duplicated, read-only, Git-only format.  That is, when you make a commit, you're directing Git to make a snapshot, like a tar or rar archive of all of your files.  This snapshot can only hold *files*, not folders; the files have names that have embedded forward slashes in them, and Git knows, later, at extraction time, to *make* folders if your computer demands them.

  The set of files that go into a commit are taken from Git's *staging area*—which, even if apparently-empty, actually has full copies of every file.  It's just that the files are all *de-duplicated* (at all times), so if they're duplicates of existing files, they take no space.

  Note that when you run `git add`, you're simply directing Git to update its full-copy-of-the-file that it *already has* in the staging area.  Well, unless this is a new file name, in which case, you're directing Git to compress and de-duplicate the file (maybe its contents match those of an old file with a *different name*) and store it in the index / staging-area.<sup>2</sup>
- Meanwhile, separate from the snapshot, each commit stores some *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  Here you'll find the `user.name` of the person who made the commit, for instance—or rather, the setting they had at that time.  You'll find their `user.email` copied here as well.  There are some date-and-time-stamps, which help ensure uniqueness even if the source snapshot didn't change.  Most important to Git itself, however, you'll find a list of *parent commit hash IDs*.

  This list usually just has one entry in it: one parent commit, for this child commit.  The parent hash ID is the commit that *was* checked out, at the time the user who made this *child* commit, made the child commit.

What all this does, then, is maintain commits as a *backwards-looking chain*.  That is, provided we know the hash ID `H` of the *latest* commit:

```
            <-H
```

we can have Git *read* commit `H`.  This commit will contain the hash ID of some earlier commit `G`: that's the arrow coming out of `H`.  We say that commit `H` *points to* earlier commit `G`:

```
        <-G <-H
```

Commit `G` of course points to some still-earlier commit `F`, which in turn points back even more:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This *is* the history, stored in the Git repository.  To find it, we just need to memorize the big ugly hash ID of the *last* commit `H`.

---

<sup>1</sup>This means that each commit you make commit in your repository gets a different number from *every* commit in *every other repository in the universe*.  We do know, for certain, that this uniqueness property is bound to fail someday.  The length of the hash determines the *probability of failure*.  The actual risk, and damage that occurs, once this fails—and it will someday—depends on when those two different Git repositories in which a different commit has the same ID actually *meet*, which might be never.  With luck, these "[doppelgänger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelg%C3%A4nger) commits", as I call them, will *never* meet.  They're only dangerous if they do meet, and even then, it's not as bad as, say, [destroying the universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alternative_Factor).  But in fact, a doppelgänger *file* would be bad too, and with SHA-1 having been [broken](https://shattered.io/), Git is moving to SHA-256, eventually, which should help.

<sup>2</sup>This thing—this index or staging area—is so important, and/or so poorly named originally, that it has *three* names.  The third name for this thing is the *cache*.  What this thing actually holds is a *blob hash ID*, referring to how Git uses hash IDs to store file data, plus the file's *name* complete with forward slashes (even if you're on Windows), plus the file's *mode* (+x or -x), plus a bunch of cache data to make Git go fast.

When you run `git add`, you're updating this `.git/index` file, or one of its subsidiaries (the format of the index has gotten quite complicated).  When you run `git rm`, you're also updating `.git/index`, this time to remove one entry.  Oddly, `git add` can remove entries too: if you remove a file from your working tree, then use `git add` to "add" that file that's currently still in Git's index, Git notices this, and `git add` behaves as `git rm --cached`.

---

#### Branch names remember hash IDs for us

Hash IDs are big and ugly and impossible to remember, e.g., [<sup>`eb27b338a3e71c7c4079fbac8aeae3f8fbb5c687`</sup>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/eb27b338a3e71c7c4079fbac8aeae3f8fbb5c687).  Would you want to memorize that one?  I wouldn't.  Fortunately, we don't have to: we have a *computer*.  Computers are great at remembering long strings of letters and digits.  We just stuff them into a file or a database, along with a simple name like `main` or `master` that *we* use to *retrieve* that ID:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

We say that this name *points to* the last commit in the chain.

If we want that commit out, we just run:

```
git checkout main
```

or:

```
git switch main
```

Git looks up the *name*, finds the hash ID, extracts the commit—retrieves all the stored files from the archive in commit `H`—and we're ready to work.

If we want a new *branch name*, we tell Git to make one, using commit `H` as the hash ID.  For instance, we might create a new name `develop` with:

```
git branch develop
```

which gives us this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, main
```

Note how both branch names select commit `H` right now.  This means all these commits are on *both branches*.  There's one obvious problem, though: `git status` says "on branch main" and we want to be `on branch develop`.  So we use a Git command, switch or checkout, to switch to `develop`.  We'd like a way to see, in our drawings, *which* branch *name* we're using to find commit `H`.  To do that, let's attach the special name `HEAD` to *one* of these two branch names:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), main
```

The name to which `HEAD` is attached—in this case, `develop`—is our *current branch name*, and the *commit selected by that name*—still `H`—is our *current commit*.

We now do some work as usual, then run `git add` and `git commit`.  Git packages up the files that are in Git's index / staging-area, adds some metadata saying that we're the author and committer of this new commit, uses the *current commit hash ID `H`* as the new commit's *parent*, and writes all of this stuff out to make a new commit, which we'll call `I`.

New commit `I` contains `H`'s hash ID, so `I` points back to `H`:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

Now that commit `I` exists, Git writes `I`'s hash ID—whatever that is—into the *current branch name*, i.e., `develop`.  So we should finish off our picture like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

The name `HEAD` is still attached to the name `develop`, but now the name `develop` selects the *last commit* for this branch, which is our *new* commit `I`.  If we make another commit, it just adds on here:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I--J   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

If we now `git checkout main` or `git switch main`, Git will attach `HEAD` to `main`, *remove* the files for commit `J`, and *extract* the files for commit `H`, and we'll have this setup:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main (HEAD)
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

If we make another branch name and make some more commits, we get:

```
             K--L   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

We now have three branch names to choose from, and hence three "last commits".  Commit `H` and all the earlier commits are on *all three* branches, while commits `K-L` are only on `feature`, with `L` as its last commit, and commits `I-J` are only on `develop`, with `J` as its last commit.

#### Everything else Git does builds on all of this

You now know all the most-fundamental things you need to know about Git:

- Commits store *snapshots and metadata*.
- Commits link to earlier commits.  This *is* the history, in a repository.
- A *branch name* finds the *last commit*, by definition.
- The special name `HEAD` finds the *current branch name*.
- Making a *new* commit simply *adds on*.  The existing commits never change.  They literally can't: the hash ID of a commit is a cryptographic checksum of every data-bit that goes into that commit.<sup>3</sup>
- Branch names *move*.  Normally, they move to *add new commits*.

You might object that when you look at a commit—e.g., with `git show` or `git log -p`—you see *changes*, not snapshots.  Git can do this because the commit has a *parent*.  The parent also has a snapshot.  Git simply extracts *both commits* (to a temporary area in memory) and *compares* the snapshots.  It computes the diff to show you *at this time*, from the two snapshots.

If you ever make a *bad* commit and want Git to forget about it, you can use `git reset`.  The reset command lets you move a branch name.  If you move the branch name "backwards"—against the normal direction of branch-name-movement—the commit, or commits, that is/are on the end kind of "fall off".  For instance, given the graph above, if we run `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, we get:

```
               L   ???
              /
             K   <-- feature (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- main
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

The commit that *used* to be last, `L`, on the current branch, is no longer last: now commit `K` is the last.  Commit `L` still *exists*, but without a name, you will have to remember—or find—its hash ID in order to *see* it.<sup>4</sup>

The cherry-pick command you've been using works by this same idea: find the commit's *parent*, and compare.  The change from parent to child is the same thing Git should do now, on whatever branch you have out, with whatever commit you have out.  Git should make the same *change* now, then make a new commit that copies the commit *log message* from the cherry-picked commit.

The result is a "copy of the commit": a commit that *makes the same change*, so that `git show` or `git log -p` shows the same diff—though the line numbers might change, in this diff—and that has the same log message.  The commit's raw hash ID will be different, though: every commit has a unique hash ID.

---

<sup>3</sup>This is arguably a mistake.  To attach extra information to a commit later—which Git allows with `git notes`, for instance—we have to go through weird contortions.  The notes system works by storing, in a special commit, a file whose *name* is the *hash ID* of some commit.  Git looks up this particular notes commit and checks to see if there's a file with the name of some commit hash ID.  The `git log` command will then display this file's contents, as the note for the commit.  Since most commits *don't* have notes, this is a lot of work to do just to discover that there isn't a note.  Clever caching makes this less painful, but it might still be nice if each commit had, say, an optional area for adding annotations to make all this easier.

(Because the notes are themselves stored in commits, every note you ever make is as permanent and unchanging as a commit.)

<sup>4</sup>Git has a whole set of things for recovering from errors, including logs of old hash IDs.  These do eventually *expire* though.  Once the log entry finding the hash ID of some "removed" commit expires, that commit becomes vulnerable to Git's *garbage collector*, `git gc`, which will remove commits that can't be found and have run out of grace period.

Comment: Thank you for your super detailed response! Your command worked like a charm and thanks to your explanation now I also know why! :) 

About your question, I'm doing a total upgrade of an active project, based on a dead framework. My idea was to create a branch where I maintain the framework-agnostic "logic" code, I delete everything else and I create a new piece of code that "encapsulates" the logic. By rebasing to main, I can keep the logic code up to date while working on the encapsulation. This approach works, but I forgot to keep a couple of files and the original branch was huge :)